# All output at last-C++ compiler

Tags: c++, io, formatting

This question might sound stupid but I really want to know that How do I get all the output at last after inputting all the input.Example,For **input**

```
  3
  14 
  7
  6
```

**Output** suppose will be

```
  0
  0
  1
  0
```

But compiler is giving output something like

```
 3
 0 14
 0 7
 1 6
 0
```

Which doesn't look good,so I want to get output like the one we get in **IDEONE**(i.e all at the last).Is this possible ?IF yes,than please let me know

Comment: It's definitely possible to make a program that outputs one number per line. We can't find the problem in your code unless you post your code. (And that output is presumably from your program, not from the compiler).

Comment: Can't do much without code :/

Answer (score 3):

I'd suppose that you read the input int by int, and the output comes as soon as another int is read, while to achieve the desired behavior you have to read them all first and then process.

```
std::vector<int> ints;

while (std::cin)
{
    int x;
    if (std::cin >> x)
        ints.push_back(x);
}

for (int x : ints)
{
    // do what you want with x
}
```

Note that the problem is definitely not the compiler, it's just how most terminals work - both standard input stream (`stdin`) and standard output stream (`stdout`) are linked with the text that you type/see in the terminal.